# Angular 2 - Pass FormControl field to a directive

Tags: forms, angular

I've been playing lately with Angular 2 forms, in particular form validation. 
The following 3 files are part of my code: app.component, app.component.html and hide-valid.directive

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/templates/app.component.html',
    directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FormBuilder]
})
export class AppComponent {
    loginForm: FormGroup;

    username: FormControl;
    password: FormControl;

    constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
        this.username = new FormControl('', [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(3)
        ]);
        this.password = new FormControl('', Validators.required);

        this.loginForm = builder.group({
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        });
    }

    onSubmit() {}
}
```

**hide-valid.directive.ts**

```
import { Input, OnInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
    selector: '[hide-valid]'
})
export class HideValidDirective {
    valid: Boolean;

    @Input() set isValid(property: FormControl) {
        this.valid = property.untouched || property.valid;
        this.set();
    }

    constructor(
        private el: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer) {
    }

    set() {
        if (this.valid) {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.el.nativeElement,
                'display', 'none');
        }
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label for="username">username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" [formControl]="username">
    <div [hidden]="username.valid || username.untouched">
        <span *ngIf="username.hasError('required')">Field is required</span>
        <span *ngIf="username.hasError('maxlength')">Field is limited to 3 characters.</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">log in</button>
</form>
```

What I want to do is to **replace** this piece of code:

```
<div [hidden]="username.valid || username.untouched">
    <span *ngIf="username.hasError('required')">Field is required</span>
    <span *ngIf="username.hasError('maxlength')">Field is limited to 3 characters.</span>
</div>
```

into this:

```
<div hide-valid isValid="{{ username }}">
    <span *ngIf="username.hasError('required')">Field is required</span>
    <span *ngIf="username.hasError('maxlength')">Field is limited to 3 characters.</span>
</div>
```

But the problem is I cannot access any **property** on username if I use this syntax. Inside my isValid(property: any) property comes as [object Object]

What did I miss? I find the second syntax much nicer and shorter than the first solution, so that's why I'm using the directive.

Answer (score 0):

`{{...}}` is for string interpolation. It stringifies every value before the assignment.

Use instead

```
<div hide-valid [isValid]="username">
```

You can also change the selector to `[isValid]` then you can shorten your code to

```
<div [isValid]="username">
```

Comment: Apparently I did something wrong in my directive as using [isValid] leads to - Can't bind to 'isValid' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Comment: No idea, this worked every time I used it. Perhaps you can add the exact code you tried to your question.